# How can I write an if statement with multiple conditions using && and ||?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am making a tic tac toe board game and I need the user to enter any position between 1 to 9 then type in X or O. Some conditions I need include is that I want to restrict the user to enter any number greater than 9 and do not enter any character either than 'X' or 'O'. The problem I encounter is that it doesn't follow the conditional statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void CreateBoard(int m, int n, char board[][n])
{
    int i, j, position;
    char one;
    char two; 
    char temp;
    char xORo;
    int count = 0;
    int end;

    do {
        printf("Enter the number of the cell you want to insert X or O or enter -1 to exit: \n");
        scanf("%d", &position);

        printf("Type X or O: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &xORo);

        if(position < 0){
            break;
        }
        if((position > 9) && xORo != ('X') && ('O'))
        {
            continue;
        }   
        else if((position > 0 || position < 9) && xORo == ('X') && ('O'))
        {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 1: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][0];
                        board[0][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 2: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][1];
                        board[0][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 3: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][2];
                        board[0][2] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 4: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][0];
                        board[1][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 5: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][1];
                        board[1][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 6: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][2];
                        board[1][2] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 7: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][0];
                        board[2][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 8: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][1];
                        board[2][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 9: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][2];
                        board[2][2] = temp; 
                        break;
            }
            PrintBoard(3, 3, board);
        }

    }while(position != -1);
}
```

Comment: `if((position > 9) && xORo != ('X') && ('O'))` should be `if ((position > 9) || (xORo != 'X' && xORo != 'O'))`

Comment: Note, that you can get rid of the `(position > 0 || position < 9)` part as you have the `switch/case` statement, where you can handle the `default` case.

Comment: `xORo != ('X') && ('O')` doesn't work the way you think it does - you have to write it as `xORo != 'X' && xOro != 'O'`.

Comment: what can I put in the default case?

Comment: If it should never happen, I would put something like `assert(0);`.

Comment: position is uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify with a little math. Given an index `i`, you can get the row/column with:

```
row = i % 3;
col = i / 3;
```

Note that `i` is `0-8` and not `1-9`.

You can use a helper function to convert an index to row/col:

```
void get_row_col(int index, int num_cols, int *row, int *col)
{
    *row = index % num_cols;
    *col = index / num_cols;
}
```

Then your function can be simplified to:

```
void CreateBoard(int m, int n, char board[][n])
{
    int position, row, col;
    char xORo;

    while (1) {
        printf("Enter the number of the cell you want to insert X or O or enter -1 to exit: \n");
        scanf("%d", &position);
        // TODO: Always check the return value from scanf

        if (position == -1) break;

        printf("Type X or O: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &xORo);

        if (position < 1 || position > 9 || (xORo != 'X' && xORo != 'Y')) {
            continue;
        }

        get_row_col(position - 1, 3, &row, &col);
        board[row][col] = xORo;
        PrintBoard(3, 3, board);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((position > 9) && (xORo !='X') && (xORo !='O'))
        {
            continue;
        }
```

This should be the second condition.

```
else if((position > 0)&&(position < 9)&&(xORo =='X') && (xORo=='O'))
```

This should be the final condition for attaining your desired motive.Also, no need to use do-while loop with condition(position!=-1), since that has already been achieved in the first condition.Instead, the following code can be used

```
while(1) {
        printf("Enter the number of the cell you want to insert X or O or enter -1 to exit: \n");
        scanf("%d", &position);

        printf("Type X or O: \n");
        scanf(" %c", &xORo);

        if(position < 0){
            break;
        }
        if((position > 9) && (xORo !='X') && (xORo !='O'))
        {
            continue;
        }   
        else if((position > 0)&&(position < 9)&&(xORo =='X') && (xORo=='O'))
        {
            switch(position)
            {
                case 1: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][0];
                        board[0][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 2: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][1];
                        board[0][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 3: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[0][2];
                        board[0][2] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 4: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][0];
                        board[1][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 5: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][1];
                        board[1][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 6: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[1][2];
                        board[1][2] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 7: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][0];
                        board[2][0] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 8: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][1];
                        board[2][1] = temp; 
                        break;
                case 9: temp = xORo;
                        xORo = board[2][2];
                        board[2][2] = temp; 
                        break;
            }
            PrintBoard(3, 3, board);
        }

    }
}
```